# Angular2: Why do I have to import a Service in a child component if it is already included in the app component?

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have a Service for authentication called AuthService. It handles JWT authentication and has a property `loggedIn`. This Service is imported in my App Component.

In the App Component I also include a Navbar Component, that displays a little navigation. I use *ngIf to either display a Login Button or a Logout Button and the currently logged in user. The values for this are provided by AuthService.

Everything works fine if I import AuthService in my Navbar Component. But not if it is only included in the App Component. I thought that imports work hierachical in Angular 2 and what I import on the parent level should be available on the child level. Or am I mistaken?

This is how I think it should work, but it doesn't:

```
// app.component.ts

import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig } from 'angular2/router';

import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../+home/index';
import { Admin } from '../shared/models/admin.model';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'fac-app',
  providers: [AuthService, Admin],
  templateUrl: 'app/components/app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavbarComponent, SecretComponent]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/secret',
    name: 'Secret',
    component: SecretComponent
  }
])
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

}
```

---

```
// navbar.component.ts

import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'fac-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/components/navbar.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class NavbarComponent {

}
```

---

```
// navbar.component.html

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a></li>
        <li><a *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn" [routerLink]="['Login']">Login</a></li>
        <li><a *ngIf="authService.loggedIn" href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p *ngIf="authService.loggedIn" class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as {{authService.currentUserDisplayName()}}</p>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

---

```
// auth.service.ts

import { Http, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { JwtHelper, AuthHttp, AuthConfig, tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Admin } from '../models/admin.model';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  token: any;
  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();

  private loggedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router, private authHttp: AuthHttp, private admin: Admin) {
    this.loggedIn = tokenNotExpired('auth_token');
  }

  saveJwt(jwt: any) {
    if(jwt) {
      localStorage.setItem('auth_token', jwt);
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
      this.loggedIn = true;
    }
  }

  getJwt() {
    if(this.isAuth()) {
      return localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    }
  }

  deleteJwt() {
    localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  }

  isAuth() {
    return tokenNotExpired('auth_token');
  }

  login(admin: Admin) {
    var header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.authHttp.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/sessions', JSON.stringify({data: {attributes: { email: admin.email, password: admin.password } }}), {
      headers: header
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.deleteJwt();
    this.loggedIn = false;
    this.router.navigate(['Home']);
  }

  currentUserDisplayName() {
    var jwt: any = this.getJwt();
    var decodedToken: any = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(jwt);
    return decodedToken.displayname;
  }

}
```

---

This is the working version:

```
// navbar.component.ts

import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

import { AuthService } from '../shared/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'fac-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/components/navbar.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Expressions in templates like `*ngIf="!authService.loggedIn"` are evaluated in the scope of the component instance. So, it's actually `navbarComponentInstance.authService.logged`. When you omit `private authService: AuthService` in the constructor function, `navbarComponentInstance.authService` is apperantly undefined.
2. "what I import on the parent level should be available on the child level." Yes, the service instance can be injected to the child component **if and only if you declare a service property in child constructor function**. And, don't add the service to the `providers` of child component if it has been added to parent's.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give an example for 2?

Comment: Your working version is actually 2. You have created a `AuthService` instance by adding it to the `providers` of `AppComponent`. Child component can assess it by declaring a proper parameter of in the constructor, which is `constructor(private authService: AuthService) {  }`. [If you are interested](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) @ØleBjarnstroem